# QLPreviewController change title?

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to change the title of an item in an QLPreviewController?

I've already tried with:

1. Subclassing QLPreviewController
2. Add

   ```
   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Bericht"
   }
   ```

But you see the title only for maybe 1/4 second.

Any ideas?

Comment: How can i rename the url without renaming the file?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you need to display a different title other than the lastPathComponent from your url, you can subclass QLPreviewItem and provide your own title implementing the optional property:

Instance Property Declaration:

```
var previewItemTitle: String? { get }
```

> The title to display for the preview item.
>
> If you do not implement a getter method for this property, or if your
>   method returns nil, QuickLook examines the URL or content of the item
>   being previewed to determine an appropriate title for display to the
>   user. Return a non-nil value for this property to provide a custom
>   title.

---

```
 protocol QLPreviewItem : NSObjectProtocol
```

> Description
>
> The QLPreviewItem protocol defines properties you implement to make your
>   application’s content visible in a QuickLook preview
>   (QLPreviewController in iOS or QLPreviewPanel in macOS). The methods
>   in this protocol are also declared as a category on the NSURL class.
>   As a result, you can use NSURL objects directly as preview
>   items—provided that you want to use the default titles of those items.
>   A default title is the last path component of an item’s URL. If you
>   want to supply your own preview item titles, create your own preview
>   item objects that adopt this protocol.

First Subclass QLPreviewItem:

```
import UIKit
import QuickLook
class PreviewItem: NSObject, QLPreviewItem {
    var previewItemURL: URL?
    var previewItemTitle: String?
    init(url: URL? = nil, title: String? = nil) {
        previewItemURL = url
        previewItemTitle = title
    }
}
```

Then in your controller you return the QLPreviewItem instead of the URL:

**Xcode 11 • Swift 5.1**

```
import UIKit
import QuickLook

class ViewController: UIViewController, QLPreviewControllerDelegate, QLPreviewControllerDataSource {

    var previewItems: [PreviewItem] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        previewItems = [
            .init(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "your file 1", withExtension: "ext"),
                  title: "Custom Title 1"),
            .init(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "your file 2", withExtension: "ext"),
                  title: "Custom Title 2"),
        ]
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        quickLook()
    }

    func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int { previewItems.count }

    func quickLook(at index: Int = 0) {
        let controller = QLPreviewController()
        controller.delegate = self
        controller.dataSource = self
        controller.currentPreviewItemIndex = index
        present(controller, animated: true)
    }

    func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem { previewItems[index] }
}
```