# Swift: How to open just one page of a PDF with QLPreviewController?

Tags: swift, xcode, nsurl, pdfkit, quicklook

I have a reference to my current link with

```
self.pdfDocument?.documentURL?.path
```

or

```
self.pdfDocument?.documentURL
```

and I have a button already that, when clicked, shows the QuickLook of the entire PDF. Here is my code to open the PDF, with some extra let statements to get a page number:

```
func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
        let documentURL = self.pdfDocument?.documentURL?.path
        let current_URL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentURL!)
        let currentPage = pdfView.currentPage
        let page_index = pdfDocument?.index(for: currentPage!)
        let pdf_URL = self.pdfDocument?.documentURL
        let page = self.pdfDocument!.page(at: page_index!)!
        return current_URL as QLPreviewItem
    }
```

Is it possible to return a QLPreviewItem with just one page of my PDF, as opposed to getting the entire PDF? For instance, if I want the 500th page out of a PDF of 1000 pages. Do I edit the URL? Is it possible with QuickLook?

The reason is because I am using Markup within QuickLook to annotate my PDF, but I only wish to have QuickLook show the page that I want (I got the page number already using code above).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you get the fileURL path ? just unwrap `if let documentURL = pdfDocument?.documentURL {`. and use `documentURL`

Comment: You can't present a single page but you can set your controller currentPreviewItemIndex using your currentPage https://stackoverflow.com/a/43057707/2303865

Comment: You would need to create a new pdf with a single page to achieve what you want.

Comment: @LeoDabus Thank you for the help. "currentPreviewItemIndex" isn't working for me - I checked your linked post as well. I only have one PDF document, and I want, for instance, page 37 out of 200. "currentPreviewItemIndex" documentation by apple says that "You can change which item is displayed, among those in a navigation list." How can I get quickLook to pop up and show immediately some page in the middle of a single PDF file, given that I already have the page number in mind?